# Problema cargar Report Viewer en modo toda la página

Tags: c#, report

Estoy programando una Aplicación de WinForms que crea un reporte. Cuando se crea el reporte tenemos dos opciones: Una opción que tenemos es la de Vista Previa y la otra opción es la de Imprimir.

Cuando elegimos **`vista previa`** obtenemos el reporte, que obtenemos con todo el ancho de la página, le damos con la rueda del ratón para ver las demás páginas y se cargan bien, pero cuando cambiamos la opción del panel superior a **`Toda la página`**, en donde se ven todas las páginas del reporte al darle a la rueda del ratón se pasa de la página 1 a la 3 sin pasar por la 2 y luego si llegamos a la página 4 y le damos para arriba se nos pasa a la página 2 sin pasar por la 3.

Estas son algunas capturas de pantalla:

1. Inicio de la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Dos opciones

[image: Dos opciones]

3. 1ª página de 4 en total

[image: 1ª página de 4 en total]

Tercera página de 4

[image: 1ª página de 4 en total]

Comment: ¿El reporte generado tiene datos en las páginas 2 y 3? - creo que este no es un problema de código, sino un problema de entender cómo usar el paginador del `ReportViewer`..

Comment: Si, el reporte tiene datos en la página 2 y en la página 3, pero a la hora de ver en modo Toda la página, se me pasa directamente de la página 1 a la 3, en vez de pasar por la 2 y luego por la 3, pero esto solamente pasa con la rueda del ratón.

Comment: Esta es una [respuesta en VB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986293/4092887). Si no ha investigado, puede buscar `reportviewer pagination mouse wheel ` a ver qué resultados puede encontrar. Puede que sea alguna configuración del ReportViewer.

Comment: puede que tenga que ver con la sensibilidad en el uso del mouse, que pasa si usan las flechas para desplearte de una pagina a otra, alli si se desplaza por todas las paginas

Comment: Si cuando utilizo las flechas para ir de una página a otra pasa por todas las páginas sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la aportación de Mauricio Arias Olave encontré la solución. Reinventé el código para pasarlo a C# y como solamente me fallaba cuando movía la rueda del ratón y estando con el reporte de la manera toda la página, nada más utilice aquello que me servía en realidad. Aquí os dejo el código hecho en C# para que sirva para más personas que se encuentren con este problema:

Lo primero que hice fui implementar en el formulario en donde tengo el reportviewer, dentro del constructor del formulario, ponemos una instrucción para inicializar el evento cuando movamos la rueda del ratón:

[image: Instrucción que ponemos en el constructor del formulario donde se encuentra el reportviewer]

Añadimos una lista llamada scrolled que luego la vamos a utilizar al principio de la clase:

[image: Lista Scrolled (Integer)]

Y añadimos el método, en el cúal entra cuando estemos en el reportviewer y le demos a la rueda del ratón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto arreglamos el problema que cuando le damos a la rueda del ratón, el reportviewer salta de dos en dos páginas, en vez de una en una.